# Get notify by Sharepoint

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, notifications, alert

I'm trying to build a Web API who'll receive notification from Sharepoint when something happend (someone upload a file, delete a file, create a directory, delete a directory etc). 
I saw that Sharepoint has Alert and Webhook but idk how make it works in my situation. If someone can tell me where to start .. !

Thank's :)

Comment: Where is your code?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remote event receiver (RER) are the way to go.

- Refer to the link on pnp site link below for walkthrough video.
  https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.EventReceivers
- A Tutorial on MSDN:
  https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/create-a-remote-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-add-ins
- The link below has a List events available, declarative provisioning code to add remote event receiver to the SharePoint Add-in project. The Elements.xml file for the remote event receiver references the web service in the web application and the remote events that you specified. 
  https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/handle-events-in-sharepoint-add-ins

Comment: Thank you, its exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would not advise RER route. That only works with ACS enabled Azure Service Bus namespace and Azure team has stopped supporting ACS. It is not possible today to create an ACS enabled Service Bus even with Azure power shell. So.. Better stay away from RER s as its future is unknown. I would look at web hooks functionality instead.